# Совпадающие строки в матрице

Tags: python

Есть двоичная матрица 10х10. Нужно найти совпадающие строки.

Я задал матрицу:

```
import random

M,N=10,10

matrix=[[random.randrange(2) for y in range(M)] for x in range(N)]
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите как быть дальше?

Comment: Теперь нужно сравнить строки. Можно это сделать с использованием нескольких циклов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [35]: matrix
Out[35]: [[0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0]]

In [36]: from itertools import combinations

In [37]: [(i,j) for i,j in combinations(range(len(matrix)), 2) if matrix[i] == matrix[j]]
Out[37]: [(0, 1)]
```

---

Python позволяет сравнивать списки:

```
In [67]: matrix[0] == matrix[1]
Out[67]: True
```

поэтому все что вам надо это перебрать все пары строк. Проще всего это сделать воспользовавшись `itertools.combinations`:

```
In [69]: list(combinations(range(len(matrix)),2))
Out[69]: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: не очень понял, можете поподробнее?

Comment: @Imao, добавил пояснения...